# How to make the plots update when I adjust parameter in Manipulate?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, differential-equations

The plots do not update when I adjust the parameter 'b'. Here is my code:

```
Manipulate[
sol = NDSolve[{V'[t]*Exp[1/V[t]]*0.2 == Cosh[T[t]/120/V[t]/b] - 1/3, 
T'[t]/120 + 2*Exp[-1/V[t]]*Sinh[T[t]] == 0.000002, V[0] == 0.01, 
T[0] == 0}, {V[t], T[t]}, {t, 0, 2000000}], 
Column[{Plot[{V[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 2000000}, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
Plot[{T[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 2000000}, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotLegends -> Automatic]}], {b, 0.5, 1, 0.1}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The form of Manipulate is

```
Manipulate[
    code;
    code;
    final_result (*what will get displayed*)
    ,  (* notice this is a COMMA *)
    control_variable,
    control_variable,
    other_options
]
```

Notice, you need ; to separate code in the body of Manipulate up to the final result that will be what is displayed followed by commas after that.

You have separated your code by commas instead.

```
Manipulate[
 sol = NDSolve[{V'[t]*Exp[1/V[t]]*0.2 == Cosh[T[t]/120/V[t]/b] - 1/3, 
    T'[t]/120 + 2*Exp[-1/V[t]]*Sinh[T[t]] == 0.000002, V[0] == 0.01, 
    T[0] == 0},
   {V[t], T[t]}, {t, 0, 2000000}
   ];
 Column[{Plot[{V[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 2000000}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLegends -> Automatic],
   Plot[{T[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 2000000}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLegends -> Automatic]}]
 ,
 {b, 0.5, 1, 0.1}
 , TrackedSymbols :> {b}]
```